# Why my Python Click command is not working?

Tags: python, python-click

Here is my project code structure:

```
pynique
├── cli
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── pynique_ops.py
├── pynique
│   ├── __init__.py
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py
```

My `setup.py` content is:

```
from setuptools import (
    find_packages,
    setup
)
print find_packages()

setup(
    name='pynique',
    version='0.1.1.dev1',
    description='pynique app',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Mozilla Public License 2.0 (MPL 2.0)'
    ],
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests']),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'jinja2',
        'PyYAML',
        'Click'
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        start-pynique=pynique.cli.pynique_ops:start
    ''',
)
```

I've done this inside pynique top folder project:
- `pip install -e .`

But my `start-pynique` is not working, it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/agung/.virtualenvs/pynique/bin/start-pynique", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pynique', 'console_scripts', 'start-pynique')()
  File "/home/agung/.virtualenvs/pynique/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/agung/.virtualenvs/pynique/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/agung/.virtualenvs/pynique/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/agung/.virtualenvs/pynique/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named cli.pynique_ops
(pynique)
```

Do you know why it failed to have module named `cli.pynique_ops`? Is there anything wrong with my setup.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally know the fix. Python setup.py install will publish all directory inside root directory (`pynique`) as a package name.

So if I was still using the same folder structure as the question stated, `cli`, `pynique` will be installed as python package. So the fix should be like this `start-pynique=cli.pynique_ops:start`.

But, instead of using that folder structure, I change it to be like this:

```
pynique
├── pynique
│   ├── cli
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── pynique_ops.py
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
```

So, I can still use `start-pynique=pynique.cli.pynique_ops:start` as the valid setup.